# In WiX, Should I have different Product Ids for 32 and 64 bit versions

Tags: wix, installation

I'm writing a WiX installer, with a common set of WiX sources for the 32 bit and 64 bit versions of the product.

The question is, should I use different Product Ids for the different versions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer my own question, which it turns out was actually the wrong one to ask, the MSDN documentation for the ProductCode property says:

> The 32-bit and 64-bit versions of an application's package must be assigned different product codes.

Turns out I was confused by the fact that I thought that the product code should never change.  This is wrong. Again:

> The ProductCode property is a unique identifier for the particular product release. This ID must vary for different versions and languages.

Answer (score 3):

First I would make a guard like this for the 32 bit installer:

```
<Condition Message="This installer does not support 64-bit Windows! ">
  <![CDATA[NOT VersionNT64]]>
</Condition>
```

and this for the 64 bit installer:

```
<Condition Message="This installer does not support 32-bit Windows! ">
  <![CDATA[VersionNT64]]>
</Condition>
```

But back to your question. I recommend that you set Product Id to "*". This ensures that every build creates a new GUID. You can always find this GUID, if you want to create a patch, using Orca.

The important value is the UpgradeCode. This GUID creates a link between versions. I will recommend one UpgradeCode for all your 32 bit installers and another UpgradeCode for all you 64 bit installers.

Comment: Windows Installer does not allow running 64 bit packages on 32 bit OS. So the latter is not neccessary: user will never see your error message.

Comment: Why do I want the first guard? It is preventing me from installing a 32 bit version of the product on 64 bit windows? Or am I misunderstanding what it does? If that is what it's trying to do, then why do I not want that?

Comment: You should prevent that people installs both a 32 bit version and a 64 bit version of your product on a Win 64 box

Comment: Don't see any inherent reason why. Depends on the app. And anyway, that's not what this does. It stops me installing the 32 bit version on a 64 bit machine. That may well be quite legitimate, depends on the application. If you really want to prevent both versions being installed then have different UpgradeCodes and use the Upgrade element to search for an existing installed copy of the other version and generate a message